# How to promisify a braintree method?

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, braintree

I'm having trouble promisifying a braintree method. Specifically, gateway.transaction.sale. https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node

I am using node.js with the bluebird library for promisification.

```
    ...
    var sale = bluebird.promisify(gateway.transaction.sale);
    return sale({
        amount: '10.00',
        paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
    });
})
.then( // doesn't reach here)
.catch(// logs out error)
```

Specifically, the .catch block at the bottom of the promise chain logs out:

```
[TypeError: this.create is not a function]
```

When not attempting to promisify, the code works fine.

```
gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: '10.00',
    paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
}, function(err, result) {
    ... no errors, everything works fine
}
```

Is this a problem with how the braintree library is implemented? Am I promisifying wrong? Are there any alternative promisification strategies I can try so I can avoid callback hell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the context parameter, aka `this`. If you're using bluebird v2, do this:

```
var sale = bluebird.promisify(gateway.transaction.sale, gateway.transaction);
```

If you use version 3, do this:

```
var sale = bluebird.promisify(gateway.transaction.sale, {context: gateway.transaction});
```

You can see this in [Bluebird's docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html).

Comment: What about adding custom callback function handler there also?

Answer (score 0):

You can promisify most of the braintree methods like this:

```
var G = {};
for(var k1 in gateway){
    if(gateway.hasOwnProperty(k1) && typeof gateway[k1] === 'object'){
        G[k1] = G[k1] || {};
        for(var k2 in gateway[k1]){
            if(typeof gateway[k1][k2] === 'function'){
                console.log('Promisify:', k1, k2);
                G[k1][k2] = G[k1][k2] || {};
                G[k1][k2] = bluebird.promisify(gateway[k1][k2], {context: gateway[k1]});

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can use them this way:

```
G.paymentMethod.find('payment_method_token').then(cb_suc).catch(cb_fail);
```