# Braintree integration - gateway.transaction.sale never reaches err, result function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, braintree

I'm using Firebase functions to integrate Braintree server-side. I've checked Firebase cloud functions with other functions and they are working fine. So, this is definitely something to do with Braintree. I checked Braintree nodejs implementation guide in github and my code is fine. https://github.com/braintree/braintree_node

**The problem is the function always goes to `catch` with `unexpectedError`. The code never reaches `then` part of the code.**

```
exports.setNonce = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

// Grab the parameters.
if (req.body.nonce === undefined) {
    // This is an error case, as "message" is required
    return res.status(400).send('No nonce defined!');
} else {
    return gateway.transaction.sale({
        amount: '5.00',
        paymentMethodNonce: 'fake-valid-nonce',
        options: {
          submitForSettlement: true
        }
      }).then((err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(406).send(err);
        }
        else {
            return res.status(200).json({"hash" : "Successful"});
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        return res.status(406).send(error);
      });
}
});
```

**Things I've already tried** -

1. Convert gateway.transaction.sale into promise by using bluebird. It still gives the same error - [How to promisify a braintree method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321458/how-to-promisify-a-braintree-method)
2. Change amount and give another nonce by selecting testing cards - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/node#test-value-2223000048400011
3. Remove `options` - Nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe because you are on a free tier (Spark), thus outgoing socket connections are blocked. You will have to upgrade your project to `Blaze plan` to enable outgoing connections. The `Blaze plan` has generous quota limits so you probably won't be charged.

Comment: Thank you. You were of great help.